# elasticsearch: create index tamplate from existing index

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, indexing

I have created an index in Elasticsearch. Now I need to create an index template for this index. I didn't find in the documentation any related with this topic. My question is : is it possible to create an index template fram an existing index in Elasticsearch? tnks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do it in two steps:

First, retrieve the index mappings and settings using

```
GET my-index
```

Then, you can use the results you got from the first steps in order to create an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html) by running

```
PUT _index_template/my_index_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["my-index-*"],
  "template": {
     "mappings": {
       ...                <--- add the mappings you got from the first call
     },
     "settings": {
       ...                <--- add the settings you got from the first call
     },
     "aliases": {
       ...                <--- add the aliases you got from the first call
     }
  },
  "priority": 200,
  "composed_of": [],
  "version": 1
}
```